# ASP script code inside ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

how to use ASP code inside ASP.NET ?

is it possible to run ASP script code inside ASP.NET page ?

If so, please give an example.

thanks

--
ASP code might look like this. So how do we such such script inside ASP.NET ?

```
Function changeColor(value, random) 
Dim colorArray
colorArray = Split(value, ",")
divBlockColor = colorArray(random Mod (UBound(colorArray) + 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Not easily, no. However, with perhaps the smallest modifications the code sample you have given above will actually port across to VB.NET very easily indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid it isn't possible, as ASP Code runs in a different application environment as asp.Net. That's also why for example `session("xyz")` is not shared between Classic ASP and ASP.Net web pages in the same website.

What you **could** do is *leave the asp code in a .asp page*, and use forms with POST to go back and forth to the asp code. This way you will **not** have to rewrite the entire .asp environment, and you can migrate to .Net one bit at a time.

[image: Principal Post ASP.Net to ASP and return values]

This way you can leave all your existing code, and use simple javascript to automatically submit the forms, posting the values back to .Net

Comment: If you need additional information, I'll be glad to provide it

Comment: What if it doesn't need any session sharing ? Isn't there any <% %> tag to say it has old ASP code ?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the project and why you would use .asp code in a .net page ?  It's like having a Ferrari, but fueling it with Diesel..